# less compile time variables

Tags: css, less

Is there a way to define a less variable at compile time?

What I would like to do is define @base-path depending on the environment that is compiling the less files so that the server references the CDN whereas the path would point to a local path on developer machines.

Comment: What tool are you compiling it with? (PHP::lessc, plessc, less.js on node.js, etc)?

Comment: I suppose it's the less.js running with node.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically define a variable in LESS CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039082/dynamically-define-a-variable-in-less-css)

Comment: I can't tell if this is a duplicate or not

Comment: @BassJobsen This doesn't seem to be a duplicate of that to me - this question seems much simpler: include environment variables in less at compile time.  The suggestion seems nothing to do with environment variables, it seems to be something complex with normal variables. I'm slightly surprised this is the only ticket talking about this.

Answer (score 0):

The lessc compiler on NodeJS, mentions the following options (from https://lesscss.org/usage/#less-options):

> #### Global Variables
>
> `lessc --global-var="color1=red"`     `{ globalVars: { color1: 'red' } }`
>
> This option defines a variable that can be referenced by the file.
> Effectively the declaration is put at the top of your base Less file, meaning it can be used but it also can be overridden if this variable is defined in the file.
>
> #### Modify Variables
>
> `lessc --modify-var="color1=red"` `{ modifyVars: { color1: 'red' } }`
>
> As opposed to the global variable option, this puts the declaration at the end of your base file, meaning it will override anything defined in your Less file.

Depending on how you call the compiler, you can insert environment variables here.