# Loop over an array of name value pairs in LESS

Tags: less

Is there some way to loop an array of name/value pairs LESS? Something like this:

```
arr = alice: black, bob: orange;

.for(arr) // something something //
   .cl-@{name} {
       background-color: @{value}
   }
```

To generate something like this:

```
.cl-alice { background-color: black; }
.cl-bob { background-color: orange; }
```

I know that you can [for-loop an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21441220/3713), but I'm unsure if it can be an array of objects rather than values in LESS.

Answer (score 16):

The answer given by @seven-phases-max works very well. For completeness you should also notice that you can do the same in Less without the imported `"for"` snippet.

from lesscss.org

> In trying to stay as close as possible to the declarative nature of
>   CSS, Less has opted to implement conditional execution via guarded
>   mixins instead of if/else statements, in the vein of @media query
>   feature specifications.

and

> In Less a mixin can call itself. Such recursive mixins, when combined
>   with Guard Expressions and Pattern Matching, can be used to create
>   various iterative/loop structures.

So in Less you could write:

```css
@array: alice black, bob orange;

.createcolorclasses(@iterator:1) when(@iterator <= length(@array)) {
    @name: extract(extract(@array, @iterator),1);
    .cl-@{name} {
        background-color: extract(extract(@array, @iterator),2);
    }
    .createcolorclasses(@iterator + 1);
}
.createcolorclasses();
```

or indeed:

```css
@array: alice black, bob orange;

.createcolorclasses(@iterator:1) when(@iterator <= length(@array)) {
    @name: extract(extract(@array, @iterator),1);
    &@{name} {
        background-color: extract(extract(@array, @iterator),2);
    }
    .createcolorclasses(@iterator + 1);
}
.cl-{
    .createcolorclasses();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Less a "pair" (in its simplest form) can be represented as an array too, so it can be as simple as:

```css
@import "for";

@array: alice black, bob orange;

.for(@array); .-each(@value) {
    @name:  extract(@value, 1);
    @color: extract(@value, 2);
    .cl-@{name} {
        background-color: @color;
    }
}
```

Note however that the ".for" thing is limited to [the only loop per scope](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/generic-for.md#multiple-loops-in-a-rule) so it's better to rewrite above to something like this:

```css
@import "for";

@array: alice black, bob orange;

.cl- {
    .for(@array); .-each(@value) {
        @name:  extract(@value, 1);
        &@{name} {
            background-color: extract(@value, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

The imported `"for"` snippet (it's just a wrapper mixin for recursive Less loops) can be found [here](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/src/for.less) (with examples [here](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/generic-for.md) and [here](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/for-each.md)).

Comment: @user1429980 you will found the .each (or .for-each) mixin at [for.less](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/src/for.less)

Comment: See also [`less-plugin-lists`](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists)

Comment: Is there a way to house only 1 key/pair in the array (with intention of adding more in the future)?  I notice if there are no commas within the definition (ie @clr_array: alice black) the extract function will treat spaces as delimiters which it says in the docs.  Is there a way to prevent spaces from being treated as such?  I guess for now I'll just list the element twice with a comment to remove the line once we actually have more than 1 pair.

Comment: @Kerry There's no difference between space-delimited and comma-delimited lists. In either case the "pair" above is an abstraction (e.g. an array of pairs can be created as space delimited list of comma delimited "pairs" etc.). I.e. a "single pair" case needs some special handling.

Answer (score 5):

While it is useful from the other answers to know that Less supports recursive functions and mixins, there is now a *much* simpler answer to this simple question.  This solution is tested to work with Less v3.9, but should work back to Less v3.7 when [each was introduced](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each).

```
.array() {
  alice: black;
  bob: orange;
}

each(.array(), {
  .cl-@{key} {
    background-color: @value;
  }
});
```

The output is tidy:

```
.cl-alice {
  background-color: black;
}

.cl-bob {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Want more?  Well, as they say, "You can haz more".  Use `@index` to use the 1-based index in the formula above.

Answer (score -2):

Here is one "[parametric mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature)" which you can use with "key:value" pairs.

Array of "key:value" pairs is defined as follows: @array: "key:value", "key:value";

```php
// imported "for" snippet (it's just a wrapper mixin for recursive Less loops)
// http://is.gd/T8YTOR
@import "for";

// loop all items and generate CSS
.generate_all(@array) {
    .for(@array);
    .-each(@item) {
        @name: e(replace(@item, ':(.*)', ''));
        @value: replace(@item, '^[^:]*:', '');
        @{name} {
            z-index: e(@value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Definition:**

```php
@array_test: ".test:9000", "header .mainNav:9000", "footer:8000", "li.myclass:5000";
```

***Test***

```php
.generate_all(@array);
```

***Result***:

```
.test {
  z-index: 9000;
}
header .mainNav {
  z-index: 8000;
}
footer {
  z-index: 7000;
}
li.myclass {
  z-index: 5000;
}
```

It works for me using **grunt + less@1.7.4**