# Apply class to all instances of parent selector in LESS

Tags: less

I've got this LESS stylesheet. The idea it to alias a lot of icon classes to my local classnames in our "namespace".

```
// base-icons.less
.base-icon {
  display: block;
  font: "myFont.otf"
}
.base-icon-foo { content: 'foo' }
.base-icon-bar { content: 'bar' }
.base-icon-fiz { content: 'fiz' }

// my-icons.less
.my-icon {
  &-foo { .base-icon; .base-icon-foo; }
  &-bar { .base-icon; .base-icon-bar; }
  &-fiz { .base-icon; .base-icon-fiz; }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent having to add the `.base-icon` class to each single line in the `my-icons.less` file? I want to apply the css to all classes that start with `.my-icon` but it would be cleaner to not have to type the `.base-icon` class each time.

Answer (score 1):

Learn [mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) and [extend](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature). E.g. (assuming you can't modify `base-icons.less`):

```
// base-icons.less

.base-icon {
    display: block;
    font: "myFont.otf"
}

// my-icons.less

.i(foo);
.i(bar);
.i(baz);

.i(@name) {
    .my-icon-@{name} {
        &:extend(.base-icon);  
        content: '@{name}';
    }
}
```

---

Also see stuff like [In LESS, can I loop over class/mixin "patterns"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705562)