# How can I possibly make this LESSCSS loop work correctly?

Tags: css, less, lesscss-resources

In my project I use 4 color themes and with this function I want to automatically assign the specific colors values contained in the variable and I want also to use the name of the variable to assign it to the class.

```
// the variables
@peach: 3399cc;
@green: ff00CC;
@orange: FF0033;
@yellow: EE0033;

@list: @peach, @green, @orange, @yellow;
```

// my LESS function

It generates the class name with the variable value: **ex: bsq3399cc**  I would like the class name to be the same as variable name: ex **bsq-peach**

I'm using .for function as documented here.
https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/for-each.md

```
.bsq {
    .for(@list); .-each(@name) {
        &@{name} {
            @color: color("#@{name}");
            li& { background: @color; }
            li& strong { background:lighten(@color, 10%); }
            li& i { background:lighten(@color, 20%); }
        }
    }
}
```

the .for mixin //

```
// ............................................................
// .for

.for(@i, @n) {.-each(@i)}
.for(@n)     when (isnumber(@n)) {.for(1, @n)}
.for(@i, @n) when not (@i = @n)  {
    .for((@i + (@n - @i) / abs(@n - @i)), @n);
}

// ............................................................
// .for-each

.for(@array)   when (default()) {.for-impl_(length(@array))}
.for-impl_(@i) when (@i > 1)    {.for-impl_((@i - 1))}
.for-impl_(@i) when (@i > 0)    {.-each(extract(@array, @i))}
```

The HTML code i use is here.

```
<ul class="testing">
    <li class="bsq3399cc"><strong>1</strong><i>10</i></li>
    <li class="bsqff00CC"><strong>2</strong><i>20</i></li>
    <li class="bsqFF0033"><strong>3</strong><i>30</i></li>
    <li class="bsqEE0033"><strong>4</strong><i>40</i></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your mistake in the snippet is that you actually do not provide those "names" for the classes (i.e. `peach`, `green`, `orange`, `yellow`) but only hex color values.
Note that in:

```
// the variables
@peach:  3399cc;
@green:  ff00CC;
@orange: FF0033;
@yellow: EE0033;

@list: @peach, @green, @orange, @yellow;
```

The `@list` is equal to `3399cc, ff00CC, FF0033, EE0033`.

I guess what you really meant is something like this:

```
@peach:  #3399cc;
@green:  #ff00CC;
@orange: #FF0033;
@yellow: #EE0033;

@list: 'peach', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow';

li.bsq- {
    .for(@list); .-each(@name) {
        @name_: e(@name);
        @color: @@name;
        &@{name_} {
            background: @color;
            strong {background: lighten(@color, 10%)}
            i      {background: lighten(@color, 20%)}
        }
    }
}
```

**---**

Additionally I would also get rid of `@green`/`'green'` duplication unless you really need those distinct variables elsewhere: see for example [Loop over an array of name value pairs in LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658087) and the last example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877100 (just opposite methods for the same approach).